# Dataset: get number of levels and elements

Tags: dataset

The summary box for `Dataset` objects shows the number of levels and elements at the bottom.

How can we get these values programmatically?

For example, "4 levels, 350 elements" in the Planets dataset:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we are not afraid of using undocumented functions, we can get the counts the same way that the summary box gets them:

```
info @ Dataset[data_, type_, _] :=
  {TypeSystem`TypeDepth[type],  TypeSystem`AtomCount[type, data]}

info @ ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}]
(* {4, 350} *)
```

Or, as per @Szabolcs' suggestion:

```
info2 @ ds_Dataset :=
  {TypeSystem`TypeDepth[#],  TypeSystem`AtomCount[##]}& @@
    Through[{Dataset`GetType, Dataset`GetData} @ ds]

info2 @ ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}]
(* {4, 350} *)
```

Comment: The old master strikes again. :D  ("Old" only respectfully, and in the sense that you were the first serious *Mathematica* user on Stack Exchange.)

Comment: I spent a few of minutes looking at the functions in `TypeSystem` and couldn't find them. Grrrr +1

Comment: I think the "official" way to get the type is ``Dataset`GetType[]`` (still undocumented, of course).

Comment: @Szabolcs I added a new variation incorporating your suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

This is not quite the same thing, but strongly related and very useful to know:

It appears that the undocumented option `AllowedHeads`, which appears in several functions in v10, can help here.

```
ds = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}];
```

To get the depth,

```
ArrayDepth[
 Normal[ds],
 AllowedHeads -> {Association, List}
]
```

This also works:

```
ArrayDepth[
 Normal[ds],
 AllowedHeads -> All
]
```

To get the element count from this generalized array,

```
Times @@ Dimensions[
  Normal[ds],
  AllowedHeads -> All
]
```

These counts refer only to the rectangular part of the generalized array made of lists and associations.  They won't give the counts 4 and 350.  For that we'd need to descend deeper.

---

Out of curiosity, this is the complete list of `` System` `` functions having this option:

```
ArrayDepth, ConjugateTranspose, Depth, Dimensions, Transpose
```

`Transpose` and `ConjugateTranspose` are useful for taking the transpose of mixed `List`-`Association` structures.

`Depth` would theoretically be good for finding the number of levels in the dataset, but I don't know how to use this option with it.  It seems to take only the values `True` and `False.`

Comment: `ArrayDepth` is same as `Dimensions /* Length`. But `Dimensions` itself is more informative for many data processing tasks.

Answer (score 5):

There's at least the brute force approach

```
getFromDs[what_String][ds_Dataset] := 
 FirstCase[ToBoxes@ds, 
  RowBox[{___, i_, Shortest@___, what, ___}] :> 
   With[{res = ToExpression@i}, res /; IntegerQ[res]], $Failed, 
  Infinity]

getLevels = getFromDs["levels"]; getElements = getFromDs["elements"];

Through@{getLevels, getElements}@ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}]

(* {4, 350} *)
```

This is an attempt at a disgusting function for the depth: the maximum number of lists or associations you can go through from the top down before bouncing in something else

We setup some tests

```
test[dep] ^= Inactivate@{
    dep[{1}] -> 1,
    dep[4] -> 0,
    dep[h[4, g[8]]] -> 0,
    dep[<|"a" -> 3|>] -> 1,
    dep[<|2|>] -> 0,
    dep[<|"a" -> 2|>] -> 1,
    dep[{<|"a" -> 2|>, d}] -> 2,
    dep[<|{2}|>] -> 0,
    dep[<|"a" -> {2}, "b" -> 8|>] -> 2,
    dep[<|"a" :> {<|"c" -> h[2]|>}|>] -> 3,
    dep[<|"x" -> {1}, "x" -> 3|>] -> 1,
    dep[<|"x" :> <|"x" -> {1}, "x" -> 3|>|>] -> 2
    };

runTest[sym_] := 
 Inactive[TestReport][
   test[sym] /. (x_ -> y_) :> Inactive[VerificationTest][x, y]] // 
  Activate
```

The code

```
dep[ds_Dataset] := dep[Normal@ds];
dep[stuff_] := idep[0, stuff];

SetAttributes[idep, HoldAllComplete];
idep[i_, l_List | 
    l_Association?(Function[i, AssociationQ@Unevaluated@i, 
       HoldAllComplete])] := 
  1 + Max[Function[x, idep[i, x], HoldAllComplete] /@ 
      Unevaluated@l /. {a_Association :> Values@a}];
idep[i_, a_Association /; 
    MatchQ[Unevaluated@a, 
     HoldPattern[
      Association[(_Rule | _RuleDelayed) ... | {(_Rule | \
_RuleDelayed) ...}]]]] :=

  Module[{v = Block[{Association = HoldComplete}, a]},
   With[{rhs = v[[All, 2]]}, 
    1 + Max[Function[x, idep[i, x], HoldAllComplete] /@ 
        Unevaluated@rhs // ReleaseHold]]];
idep[i_, _] := i;
```

When we run the tests we see that the last one failed `runTest[dep]["TestsFailed"]`. That was expected. I don't know exactly how it makes sense to design this. The fact that associations don't become associations until they are evaluated, plus the fact that one has the possibility of holding any of its arguments through using `:>` instead of `->` makes it confusing. Should one count as valid associations that aren't yet associations but are lexically well written? This does that, but this assumes that all valid unevaluated associations are `Associations` with a list or sequence of rules inside, and doesn't check if those rules may have repeated keys which might end up deleting an element, and you can't really check without evaluating them and leaking.

Comment: One could probably get the number of elements similary, taking the `Total` instead of `1 + Max`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of calculating the number of levels and elements. It first extracts the Values of each Association and then uses the resulting List to calculate the numbers. It would be nice to know if there is a simpler way of calculating the number of levels from the List.

```
levelsAndElements[data_Dataset] := Module[{lists, elements, levels},
  lists = Normal@data //. assoc_Association :> Values[assoc];
  elements = Length@Flatten[lists];
  levels = Depth[DeleteCases[lists, Except[_List], Infinity]] - 1;
  {levels, elements}]

levelsAndElements[ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}]]
```

> ```
> {4, 350}
> ```